# Using user defined math functions when compiled with a macro, or simply use the function from a standard math library in c++

Tags: c++, macros

I have my own implementation of a f_sin(x) function,(analogous implementation to sin(x) in ) that I want to use when compiled with a macro named MYMATH. If the MYMATH is not defined I want to use the function sin(x) from the math.h

Any leads on how to go about?

Note I cannot change anything in the function definitions of f_sin(x) or sin(x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a macro for each function and then just define it depending on your macro MYMATH. Also if you prefer avoiding this kind of macros you can use a generic lambda as a wrapper.

MyMath.hpp

1.- With Macros for each function

```
#ifdef MYMATH
#define imp_sin(x) f_sin(x)
#else
#include <cmath>
#define imp_sin(x) std::sin(x)
#endif
```

2. With generic lambda (C++ 14)

```
#define glambda(x) [](auto y){ return x(y); }
#ifdef MYMATH
auto imp_sin = glambda(f_sin);
#else
#include <cmath>
auto imp_sin = glambda(std::sin);
#endif
#undef glambda //Or not if you want to keep this helper
```

Usage main.cpp

```
#include "MyMath.hpp"
int main(int, char**) {
  imp_sin(3.4f);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
double sin_wrapper(double x) {    
#ifdef MYMATH
    return f_sin(x);
#else
    return std::sin(x);
#endif
}
```

and then replace all calls to `sin` with calls to this wrapper.

Comment: what if i want to only use the name f_sin(x) that will call std::sin(x) when MYMATH is not defined and when MYMATH is defined it will call the f_sin(x). Is this even possible? Note I cannot change anything in the function definitions.

Comment: @DeepakKiran then rename the wrapper to f_sin and replace the call to f_sin in my example with its implementation

Comment: @DeepakKiran i missed the "without changing the function definition". But then i dont understand what you want. Perhaps edit the question to clarify what you can change and what not and how you want the call to look like